# Default option in a <select> tag

Tags: javascript, html, select, knockout.js, default

does anybody know, how i can select the default option in a  tag (the selected="selected" does not work). I am using knockout too.

Here the code:

```html
                                <div class="input-group btn-group">
                                    <select style="width:100%" data-bind="select2: {}, options: $root.AvailableCRSListComputed, optionsText: 'Text', optionsValue: 'Value', selectPicker: $root.CoordinateSelecterFromMap" class="form-control"></select>
                                </div>
```

$root.AvailableCRSListComputed has all elements in it.
I would want to change which of these elements is shown by default in the select box.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

tie the first option as seleted like:

```html
<select class="custom-select">
      <option selected disabled>Open this select menu</option>
      <option value="1">One</option>
      <option value="2">Two</option>
      <option value="3">Three</option>
    </select>
```

then bind the select2 options using your method.